# client cant read from server with readLine

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I have a made a socket connection between client and server. Everything is working good if i introduce the first comand on client, receiving the message i want from the server.

```
#server
public PrintWriter out; 
out.println(res);
#client
public BufferedReader in = null;
String line;
line = in.readLine();
```

At the second time i run it won't show the message i send from server cause it will read \n so it will be an empty string. If i change this:

```
#server 
out.println("\n"+res);
```

The first time i run now it will jump a line, printing just the \n. And the second time i run it will show the right message. 
If i change now to:

```
out.println("\n\n"+res);
```

It will just show when i introduce something to send to the server and receive back after the 3rd time (the first 2 times it prints \n). 
Don't know what to do to show always the message i send from the server. Any advice?

Comment: Just `replace` the `\n` with `""`

Comment: That's a space or an empty string?

Comment: I am thinking an empty string

Comment: it doesn't work either way

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: i tried both ways:
out.println(""+res);
out.println(" "+res);

Comment: No I was meaning on the client side do `line.replace ("\\n", "");`

Comment: do you mean line.replace ("\n", "");
or its 2 sidebars

Comment: again, i tried both ways and it's still not working. I can't understand the problem with readLine cause i print always the message from server before send and it's correct...